# How to compare fluctuation/standard deviation across several datasets?

Tags: r, regression, anova, variance, standard-deviation

I have a set of humidity and temperature readings for several different locations on the same site. I am trying to determine whether these readings are fluctuating more in certain areas.

I've got the quarterly average and standard deviations for each location, going back about 5 years. They have the same units and are within roughly the same range (let's say between 50 and 70 for humidity, between 10-25 for temperature).

How can I compare standard dev and temperature fluctuation across these areas? For averages I can just create a single average for each quarter across all 5 years and compare, but I've read that standard deviation and variance don't work in the same way.

I do have access to the entire raw data for each location, if quarterly standard deviation comparisons would be too complex, but would prefer to keep things quarterly just for the sake of consistency.